# squid3 FAIL with cache_peer round-robin on 127.0.0.1 different port

Tags: load-balancing, squid, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 tunnels end to a Debian running squid3 (ports 9001 to 9003). At start of each tunnel runs a proxy. I try to load-balance those proxies this way:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 4128
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 sibling 9001 round-robin
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 sibling 9002 round-robin
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 sibling 9003 round-robin
```

When I restart squid3 get FAIL at line 3. I also try `parent` instead of `sibling`. Same fail.

FYI, if I set to clients to debian's IP with port 9001 or 9002 or 9003, works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify **name** option for each of **cache_peer**.
Quote from the [cache_peer documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/):

> name=xxx --- Unique name for the peer. Required if you have multiple peers on the same host but different ports.

So your **cache_peer** configuration should look like this

```
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 9001 0 name=A round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 9002 0 name=B round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 9003 0 name=C round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 9004 0 name=D round-robin no-query no-digest
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution eventually!

Edit `/etc/hosts` and add:

```
127.0.0.1       tunnelproxy1
127.0.0.1       tunnelproxy2
127.0.0.1       tunnelproxy3 
127.0.0.1       tunnelproxy4
```

Then go to `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` and:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 3128
cache_peer tunnelproxy1 parent 9001 0 round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer tunnelproxy2 parent 9002 0 round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer tunnelproxy3 parent 9003 0 round-robin no-query no-digest
cache_peer tunnelproxy4 parent 9004 0 round-robin no-query no-digest
never_direct allow all
```

If you think there is better solution, please fell free :)

Comment: Why not just use "localhost" instead of "tunnelproxy*" ?